# Elasticsearch Python - Index Analyzer & Search Analyzer

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch

I am using python api - http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org

How can I set change the index analyzer and tokenizer for the index? Thanks

I found suggestions to change the mapping of the index, but there was no documentation on how to do that from python.

[Partial Search using Analyzer in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940026/partial-search-using-analyzer-in-elasticsearch) shows settings for n-gram-analyzer but no code to implement it in python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
client.indices.create(
    index=index,
    body={
      'settings': {
        # just one shard, no replicas for testing
        'number_of_shards': 1,
        'number_of_replicas': 0,

        # custom analyzer for analyzing file paths
        'analysis': {
          'analyzer': {
            'file_path': {
              'type': 'custom',
              'tokenizer': 'path_hierarchy',
              'filter': ['lowercase']
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    # Will ignore 400 errors, remove to ensure you're prompted
    ignore=400
)
```

Check the [examples here.](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/example/load.py)

Comment: The use of `ignore=400` would cause this request to fail silently if an index already exists.  You probably want to see an error in this case :)

Comment: @DrTech added further info.

Comment: How to achieve this using python? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html